# How do I remove muItiple items from a ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

This code isn't working. It doesn't raise an exception or even do anything visible.

```
private void RemoveSelectedFiles()
{
    lstPhotos.Items.Remove(lstPhotos.SelectedItems);
}
```

How can I remove the selected items from a ListBox?

Comment: where and when does RemoveSelectedFiles get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove one item at a time.

**EDIT** - as @Smith pointed, the code would raise an exception because `ListBox.SelectedItems` is bound to the `Items` collection. Removing a selected item from `Items` will effectively remove it from `SelectedItems` too, thus breaking the enumeration. Now we enumerate an independent list containing the selected items:

```
private void RemoveSelectedFiles()
{
    var selectedItems = new List<object>(lstPhotos.SelectedItems);

    foreach (object item in selectedItems) 
        lstPhotos.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: this code throws an error `List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change.`

Comment: Thanks for testing this, @Smith.